# What is the simplest way with this

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this :

```
var originalList = from x in db.Products
                            where x.Id == 2
                            orderby x.Ip
                            select x;
```

Now I have a resultset( for example 10 rows fetched). I want to update a field of all rows
for example x.name one by one. something like this :

```
 foreach (//the fetched rows )
        {
            //x.name = "jack";
        }
```

what is the simplest way?

Comment: Please change your title with your specific problem..

Comment: And also specify "simple". It's a rather subjective word. Simple to write? Simple to read? Simple to maintain? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var product in x)
    product.Name = "Jack";
```

Is that simple enough?

<s>As a side note, I don't believe your call to `select` is actually adding anything.</s>

Comment: Apart from the fact that you *have* to use either a select clause or a group clause in a linq query expression. =)

Comment: Doh - thanks! I almost never use the query syntax so I guess I have just learned something.

Comment: Yeah, in regards to method syntax (which I also prefer) you're right. You don't have to use `Select` unless you want do a transform of some kind. =)

Answer (score 2):

Can use `originalList.ForEach` LINQ function, that internally uses simple `for` loop, which helps you *iterate and modify* collection contemporary.

In case of simple `foreach` loop, it *may* raise an exception (depends on *what* and *how* you change inside)

```
originalList.ToList().ForEach(product => {
    product.Name = "Jack";
});
```

Comment: Out of interest, why would a `foreach` loop cause an exception when changing a property? Of course it would raise an exception if you were trying to add/remove items from the list, but not updating properties on the items in the list.

Comment: @DanielKelley: as I said it **may** raise an exception. In simple property change it should not, but if that change in some way is going to alter collection's state (add, remove elements) it will. Mine was just a note..It *depends* how all stuff is implemented.

Comment: @Tigran: As far as I can see the originalList won't be an `IList` type. so therefore the `ForEach` Method won't be available. You'll need to call the `ToList()` Method first (e.g. `originalList.ToList().ForEach(pro...`)

Comment: @Nicholas: nailed, corrected.